# Another Xpath dilemma

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Ok, First the code:

```
<tr class="tableControlDataRow evenRow twTableTR">
<td class="twTableTD details" align="center" rowspan="2">
<td class="twTableTD details" align="center" rowspan="2">
    <p>
    <br>
    **<p>**
        <b>Model Number:</b>
        QA GM 05132014 1038 Item 1 Model Number
    </p>
    <p>
    <p>
    <p>
    <p>
</td>
<td class="twTableTD" align="center" rowspan="2">May-27-2014</td>
<td class="twTableTD" align="center">France</td>
<td class="twTableTD" align="center">Yes</td>
<td class="twTableTD" align="center">
    <input id="hiddenCountryAuthorizationField0_0" type="hidden" name="tw#local#quoteComparison#0#country#0#authorizationStatusId#" value="0">
    <input id="CountryAuthorizationYES0_0" class="qclCheckbox" type="checkbox" onclick="chooseAuthorization(0,0,'Yes','1')">
    Yes
    <br>
    <input id="CountryAuthorizationNO0_0" class="qclCheckbox" type="checkbox" onclick="chooseAuthorization(0,0,'No','2')">
    No
    <br>
</td>
```

Now the question...  I have found the correct starting spot by doing a

```
//p[contains(., "QA GM 05132014 1038 Item 1 Model Number")]
```

This gets me to the ** portion of the code.  Now I need to traverse up to the `<tr class="tableControlDataRow evenRow twTableTR">` at the top, then travel back down the chain to click the

```
<input id="CountryAuthorizationYES0_0" class="qclCheckbox" type="checkbox" onclick="chooseAuthorization(0,0,'Yes','1')">
```

text box.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First find the `tr`, that has `p` tag with the appropriate text, and then go down to the desired `input`:

```
//tr[.//p[contains(., "QA GM 05132014 1038 Item 1 Model Number")]]/td/input[@id="CountryAuthorizationYES0_0"]
```

Just note that there are certainly multiple ways to write the xpath here. Hope this one works for you.

Comment: @GregMa could you share a link to the page you are parsing?

Comment: It's internal, so can't.  But I did figure it out.  Looks like the code I pasted was incorrect.  I used @id, 'CountryAuthorizationYES' and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest `//p[contains(text(),'QA GM 05132014 1038 Item 1 Model Number')]/ancestor::tbody[1]//input[@id='CountryAuthorizationYES0_0']`. It will search element which contains 'QA GM 05132014 1038 Item 1 Model Number' text, then search first parent element tbody and then desired input starting from first (parent) tbody

Answer (score 0):

It ain't pretty, but this code might help you:

```
//p[contains(., "QA GM 05132014 1038 Item 1 Model Number")]//parent::br/parent::td/parent::tr//input[@id='CountryAuthorizationYES0_0']
```